# Assemble: Dynamic or Conditional Partials

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

Currently using Assemble to create static HTML files via Handlebars.

I have defined a default.hbs below:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        {{> head }}
    </head>
<body class="{{page.basename}}">
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
  <div class="inner-wrap">

    <!-- Off Canvas Menu -->
    {{> mobile-nav}}
    <!-- END Off Canvas Menu -->

    <!-- Header -->
    {{> header }}
    <!-- END Header -->

    <!-- Navigation -->
    {{> navigation }}
    <!-- END Navigation -->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row collapse" id="bcrumbs">
        {{> breadcrumbs }}
      </div>
      <!-- END breadcrumbs -->

      <div class="row collapse" id="body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-10 medium-push-2 columns" id="main-content">
            {{> body }}
          </div>
          <!-- END Main Content -->
          <div class="small-12 medium-2 medium-pull-10 columns" id="sidebar">
            {{> sidebar }}
          </div>
          <!-- END Sidebar -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END #body -->
    </div>
    <!-- END site body -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    {{> footer }}
    <!-- END Footer -->

    <!-- close the off-canvas menu -->
    <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
    </div> <!-- END off-canvas inner-wrap -->
</div><!-- END off-canvas wrap -->  

<!-- Load body scripts -->
{{> javascripts }}
```

This layout will be used throughout the project with the exception of the home page. The 'gotcha' I'm trying to work around is that the `sidebar.hbs` partial will have different content / links in the sidebar. Basically, that's all that would change about the sidebar is the content with in.

Sidebar.hbs for reference:

```
<ul class="side-nav">
    <li class="heading">Learn About GeneAware</li>
    <li><a href="#">Definition Glossary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Diseases &amp; Disorders Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Next Steps</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to avoid is duplicating the `default.hbs` just to replace `{{> sidebar}}` with 14 different sidebars.

Answer (score 3):

#### Unique IDs

This is just one strategy, but it's simple. If you put a unique identifier in the YAML front-matter of each page it will come in handy later. This is easily done when you add a `title` property or any other content. `slug` is a good one to use because it can be used in permalinks or in conditional handlebars expressions etc. A `slug` should have no spaces, be lowercase, and use dashes not underscores if it might end up in permalinks.

If `slug` doesn't work for you, use whatever makes sense, but `basename` probably isn't a good one for this purpose b/c it could be `index`, which might belong to more than one file, and properties like `title` might be a sentences.

#### YAML front matter

Add the following to the `about` page:

```
---
title: About
slug: about
---

<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

#### The actual `sidebar` partial

In a file named `sidebar.hbs` add something like this:

```
<ul class="side-nav">
{{#each .}}
  {{! `slug` is our unique identifier for each page }}
  {{#is @root.page.slug slug}}
    {{#links}}
      {{#if separator}}
      <li class="divider"></li>
      {{else}}
      <li{{#if modifier}} class="{{modifier}}"{{/if}}>
        {{#if link}} <a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a> {{else}} {{text}} {{/if}}
      </li>
      {{/if}}
    {{/links}}
  {{/is}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

#### Use the `sidebar` partial

Add the following to the layout where you want the sidebar to be injected. The `isnt` block helper will ensure that the sidebar doesn't render on pages that shouldn't have it.

```
{{#isnt slug 'home'}}
  {{> sidebar sidebar }}
{{/isnt}}
```

Another approach is to add a property to the YAML front-matter that is used to decide when to use a sidebar. Something like:

```
{{#if sidenav}}
  {{> sidebar sidebar }}
{{/if}}
```

And in the front matter:

```
---
title: About
slug: about
sidenav: true
---

<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

This is a balance, it can get out of hand if you start using this strategy for everything.

#### Sidebar data file

Now, create a `sidebar.yml` file, and add the following (with your own data obviously):

```
# About page
- slug: about
  links:
  - modifier: heading
    link: true
    url:  '#'
    text: Learn About GeneAware
  - link: true
    url:  '#'
    text: 'Diseases & Disorders Search'
  - separator: true
  - link: true
    url:  '#'
    text: Next Steps

# Contact page
- slug: contact
  links:
  - modifier: heading
    link: true
    url:  '#'
    text: Foo
  - link: true
    url:  '#'
    text: Bar
  - separator: true
  - link: true
    url:  '#'
    text: Baz
```

In case you prefer JSON, I put this together so you can pick: https://gist.github.com/jonschlinkert/f8cd6c777ca0c20d63ff.

#### Assemble options

Make sure you tell Assemble where the `sidebar.yml` data file is by defining it in the options, e.g.:

```
options: {
  data: ['data/sidebar.yml']
}
```

Comment: Incredibly thorough explanation, thank you so much! Giving it a try right now and I'll report feedback shortly!

Comment: Ran through each step, decided on json format, no errors, but the page is returns empty space where the links should be.